# PyDev doesn't recognize the __package__ attribute

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

PyDev code analysis understands the special `__file__` and `__name__` attributes but `__package__` gets flagged as undefined variable. Is this a missing feature, by design, or user error?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PythonCompletionWithBuiltinsPython3Test](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev/tests_completions/org/python/pydev/ast/codecompletion/PythonCompletionWithBuiltinsPython3Test.java) and [PythonCompletionWithBuiltinsTest](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev/tests_completions/org/python/pydev/ast/codecompletion/PythonCompletionWithBuiltinsTest.java) unit-tests inside the [Pydev](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev) github repository, it seems that it supports builtin `__file__`, `__name__`, `__init__`, `__dict__`, `__path__` but ignores `__package__` and some other variables.

I've tested that myself using the [PyDev extension in the VSCode](http://www.pydev.org/vscode) and got a similar response:

[image]

But, there is a feature called [Forced Builtins](https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins) which for my VSCode PyDev plugin was set automatically as follows (also you can set it according the link I've mentioned):

[image]

However, it appears that the `__package__` variable is still not recognized. Actually, it helps me in the auto-completion but after writing, it gives an `Undefined variable: __package__` error.